# How to run executable file using batch file and change current directory while keeping cmd window open

Tags: batch-file, cmd, python-venv

Basically I've started working on a new Django project and I want to automate activating virtual environment and then changing the current directory to the project root (while virtualenv is activated).
So far I put this `.bat` into `Scripts` folder:

```
%~d1
cmd /k activate.bat
cd ..
cd new_website
```

but `cd` commands get ignored. Now, as I understand, `cmd /k` will open new window, hence the `cd` not working. I also tried:

```
%~d1
activate.bat
cd ..
cd new_website
```

Which was my first effort, but now cmd window closes immediately, (same with `.\activate.bat`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are too many examples of this already asked and answered for me to bother providing links for you, just use `Call`. Open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to find out what it does, and how to use it!

Comment: Yes, I tried `call` but it also closes the window. The workaround I stated in the answer works for me, but I will definitely do some research and provide updates if I find something useful

Comment: Once your code has ran the `cd` commands, there's nothing else to do, so the script ends!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by modifying `activate.bat` file in `Scripts` folder by adding two `cd` commands at the very end:

```
cd ..
cd new_website
```

and removed `cd` from `.bat` file:

```
%~d1
activate.bat
```

Now, by running this `.bat` I get virtualenv activated and path is set to the project root. I would love to see other solutions for this problem.